# After Pull Request, "Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by N commits"

Tags: git, jira, pull-request

**Target**

I want my local `master` to be matched with `origin/master`, as they have the same code.

**Background**

I'm not new to `git`, but I am new to Pull Requests and working into a team of developers.

We have 2 main branches: `master` and `pre`. We use Jira to create new branches, associated to features or incidents.

Our git flow is as follows:

1. Open a branch from `pre` (using Jira)
2. Code into branch
3. Create a Pull Request to merge back to `pre` (reviewed)
4. Again PR to merge to `master` (reviewed). We are in the process to implement some testing stage in `pre`, but right now is an empty step. So, once your new PR is approved goes from `new-branch` to `pre`, and without further reviews from `pre` to `master`.

**What I did yesterday**

So, I `git checkout feature-branch` in my local environment, made some modifications, `git commit` and `git push origin feature-branch`. The code was already on the remote repo, on Github.

I went to Github and created a PR (from Github website), assigning a reviewer. The reviewer approved it so I went to Github and clicked Merge button. Repeated this twice `branch` >> `pre` >> `master`, due to the mentioned reason.

**Today, the issue**

I want to work in another task. From my `master` branch in my local environment when I `git pull origin master`, I get this message:

```
From https://github.com/<user>/<reponame>
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

And `git status` outputs this:

```
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 5 commits.
#   (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
#
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

The first time I pulled, modifications were pulled from origin/master, but now this message gets appearing.

This repo has been used only by me these last days, so the code is exactly the same.

**The questions**

I didn't merge the code locally from `feature-branch` to `pre` to `master`. Should I?

What is happening here and how can I solve it?

**PS:** I read many answers but most of the Q/A are related to working on a local branch, not pushing the code to remote repo, which throws the same message.

Comment: what does `git status` show on your `master` in local ? ?

Comment: Hi @Dev-vruper what you see in my question is `git status` output. I will edit it. Sorry

Comment: Try to do a `git fetch` and then `git diff master origin/master`. This will show if there's any difference between your remote and local master

Comment: `git diff master origin/master` returns nothing

Comment: Oh, but it solved the issue @Dev-vruper! Probably `git fetch` was what I needed. Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: cool. i've posted it as an answer as well ,incase someone refers it.

Comment: Please be aware that git doesn’t have pull-requests. These are processes made by git repo hosting sites, like GitHub and Bitbucket

Comment: yes, I am aware. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Git fetch` is what needed to be done here to update the refs .

From [git fetch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#_description) Documentation :

> Fetch branches and/or tags (collectively, "refs") from one or more
> other repositories, along with the objects necessary to complete their
> histories. Remote-tracking branches are updated (see the description
> of  below for ways to control this behavior).

Basically it means that `git` will collect all the meta-data about the commits from `remote` repo and save it on your local repo ,without modifying any files.